# Слияние веток в Git-е: непонятный конфликт строк

Tags: git, контроль-версий

Всем доброго времени суток.

Изучаю Git. Использую гуй SourceTree. Репозиторий лежит на BitBucket. Создал два аккаунта, чтоб воспроизвести совместную разработку. 
Когда делаю слияние изменений в одной ветке - в блок HEAD помещается только конфликтные строки. Когда делаю слияние изменений из разных веток - в этот блок попадают все строки.

Например, два автора меняют одну и ту же строку в файле `index.php` в ветке `master`. Мой воображаемый "напарник" успешно пушит свои изменения. А вот я уже должен выполнить слияние, перед тем как отправить свои изменения. Делаю пул. Файл принимает следующее состояние:

```
<?php

<<<<<<< HEAD
echo "This is my master branch";
=======
echo "This is test branch";
>>>>>>> 18baca2cbbf6685dbe946554f436312e93bd4ff3
exit();

// I don't have new ideas... (((
```

Тут всё понятно. Строка `echo...` является конфликтной и я самостоятельно решаю что мне с ней сделать. А теперь представим тот же файл `index.php`, но из разных веток. Отличия между ними лишь в том, что в ветке `test` появляется две строки: одна из них пустая, а вторая содержит комментарий. Как мне подумалось, слияние должно вообще пройти без проблем в автоматическом режиме, ведь нет никаких разных изменений в одной и той же строке. Однако, здравствуйте. Содержимое файла `index.php` при попытке слияния:

```
<?php

<<<<<<< HEAD
echo "This is master branch";
exit();

// I don't have new ideas... (((
=======
// This is my test branch

echo "This is master branch";
exit();

// I don't have new ideas... (((
>>>>>>> test
```

И в конце файла ещё одна пустая строка (после строки `>>>>>>> test`).

На этом моменте я завис. Не могу понять откуда вообще появились конфликтные строки. Их быть не должно. Ведь в тесте всего лишь 2 новые строки, не более. Кто может мне объяснить, где я чего не понял? Это так и должно быть, или я, криворукий, где-то допустил ошибку, которая приводит к такому результату?

Заранее благодарю за помощь.
С уважением, Юрий.

Comment: Есть мысль, что настройка CRLF не верная, и git видит различные концы строк и ругается.

Comment: @KoVadim настройки CRLF действительно разные (гит "напраника" на виртуалке Hyper-V, и я там ставил другие настройки). Но я не думал, что это может так сильно повлиять. К тому же я не совсем разобрался что это такое...

Comment: читайте, разбирайтесь http://jenyay.net/Git/Autocrlf
потом отпишитесь, как было.

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо, почитал. Действительно, проблема именно в окончаниях строк. Правда, пока я читал и тестировал был дан развёрнутый ответ ниже. Не менее полезный. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если у двух строк разные окончания - то они считаются гитом различными. Поэтому важно правильно договариваться об окончаниях строк внутри команды.

Также есть вариант принудительно настроить окончания строк для репозитория, это делается в файле .gitattributes

Пример настройки в этом файле:

```
*.cs text eol=crlf
```

Здесь написано, что все файлы с расширением `.cs` надо считать текстовыми, хранить в репозитории с LF окончаниями строк - а в рабочей копии загружать с окончанием строк CRLF.

Или вот другой пример:

```
*.xml text eol=lf
```

Здесь во всех xml-файлах окончания строк всегда будут LF.

---

Немного о том, что вообще такое "окончания строк". Окончание строки - это набор невидимых символов, которые отделяют в файле одну строку от другой. Исторически, имеется два разных символа, которые пришли к нам еще с пишущих машинок и телетайпов:

- CR - возврат каретки, этот символ возвращал каретку в начало текущей строки
- LF - перевод строки, этот символ переводил каретку к следующей строке, не смещая ее

Для электрических печатных машинок или матричных принтеров это были две разные команды (а у машинок - еще и две разные кнопки). Но когда встала задача обработки текстов на компьютере, два разных символа оказалось избыточно, поэтому некоторые системы пошли по пути упрощения.

В современном UNIX-мире сейчас принято разделение строк при помощи одного символа LF, на старых маках использовался символ CR - ну а DOS и потом винда остались на CRLF.

Тем не менее, все нормальные текстовые редакторы сейчас уже умеют автоматически определять окончания строк или даже работать со смешанными окончаниями строк в одном файле - поэтому вы про них ничего и не знали.

Но git работает не с текстом, а с байтами - поэтому в гите важно приводить окончания строк для файла к одному виду.

Comment: Про различное окончание строк я знал. Правда, я сталкивался с ними не как с `CR` и `LF`, а как `\r` и `\n`, потому и не понял о чём речь. И я действительно думал, что гит работает с текстом, а не байтами. Вот потому-то и проблема вышла. Спасибо вам за разъяснение. Но вопрос, если я укажу в репе `*.php text eol=lf`, а сам буду работать под Windows, окончание строк в любом случае будет `LF`? А что если у напарника (тоже винда) будет в гит-конфиге выставлена настройка `autocrlf = true`? В случае `input` или `false` проблем быть не должно по идее. А если `true`?

Comment: P.S.: если файл `.gitattributes` положить в корень директории локального репозитория, то разве он не будет распространятся только на одну ветку? Его можно сделать общим для всех веток, не добавляя его во все ветки по отдельности?

Comment: @intro94 настройки gitattributes имеют приоритет перед локальными.

Comment: @intro94 что же до веток - наверное, лучше всего добавить его во все ветки. В идеале - его надо добавлять *до* образования веток.

Comment: я сейчас просматривал офф. доки по .gitattributes, [тут](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) и [тут](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/Настройка-Git-Git-атрибуты). Там шла речь о файле `.git/info/attributes`. Это то, что я думаю? Клонируемое пр клоне репозитория и тд?

Comment: @intro94 нет. .git/info/* - это локальные файлы, которые действуют только на одну копию репозитория

Comment: @intro94 такие файлы стоит применять если настройки из них актуальны для вас одного. Например, ваша конкретная IDE понимает только одно конкретное окончание для строк в файлах.